# Unable to start Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start in windows 10 machine

Tags: docker

Trying to run docker in windows 10 real machine. Its throws error says "Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running."

Comment: Have a look in your system's services list and check whether the Hyper-V services are installed and running.

Comment: Hyper-v is installed and running

Comment: perhaps this might help you?  http://abhijitkakade.com/2020/05/docker-on-windows-with-linux-containers/

Comment: I have checked the above article. Under task manager I do have virtual machine "yes" not virtualization "enabled". Also am running docker in windows virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

We just solved this problem!

The error was

> The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 109BC34D-AEE6-4980-B6B8-03C3D6CED10B).

In our case, we were try to run Docker from a virtual machine running on top of Hypervisor. To fix it, we went to the host server that is running the virtual machines and ran below command:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName "My VM" -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Replace "My VM" with the name of your VM, the one where you're installing docker.

Remember to run the command from the host computer. Also the VM must be turned off before running the command else you'll get an error.

Refer to this github trail for more information: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4470#issuecomment-674444273